# How can I get collection from firestore database into QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on my flutter project. Below is the function in which I tried to get a collection of recipe from firestore database and map it. I am getting error in the this line:

```
QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> recipesSnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').get();
```

The android studio suggest me two choices, first choice is cast this `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').get()` as `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` then when I run the program it shows me this error

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast

The second choice is to change `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` to `Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` but then I can't access in `recipesSnapshot.docs`

```
  Future<List> getRecipeDataList() async {
    List recipes = [];
    //try {
      int count =  await getRecipeCount();
      int recipeID = 101;
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, recipeID++) {
        if (await checkIfRecipeDocExists(recipeID.toString()) ==
            true) {
          QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> recipesSnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').get();
          for(QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in recipesSnapshot.docs){
            recipes.add(
              Recipes(
                recipeID: doc.id,
                recipeName: doc.get('recipe_name'),
                recipeDescription: doc.get('recipe_description'),
                recipeURL: doc.get('recipeImageURL'),
                recipeRating: doc.get('recipe_rating'),
                recipeTime: doc.get('recipe_time'),
                recipeIngredients: doc.get('recipe_ingredients'),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      }
      return recipes;
    //} catch (e) {
      //return [];
    //}
  }
```

Database reference:

[image]

How can I solve this?

I tried different method from the internet but didn't find the perfect solution.

**Updated Code:**

```
Future<List> getRecipeDataList() async {
    List recipes = [];
    int count = await getRecipeCount();
    int recipeID = 101;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, recipeID++) {
      if (await checkIfRecipeDocExists(recipeID.toString()) == true) {
        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> recipesSnapshot =
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').get();
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in recipesSnapshot.docs) {
          recipes.add(
            Recipes(
              recipeID: doc.id,
              recipeName: doc['recipe_name'],
              recipeDescription: doc['recipe_description'],
              recipeURL: doc['recipeImageURL'],
              recipeRating: doc['recipe_rating'],
              recipeTime: doc['recipe_time'],
              recipeIngredients:
                  (doc['recipe_ingredients'] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>(),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return recipes;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to have `await` on getting `QuerySnapshot`

Make your code as following

```
  Future<List> getRecipeDataList() async {
    List recipes = [];
    //try {
    int count =  await getRecipeCount();
    int recipeID = 101;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, recipeID++) {
      if (await checkIfRecipeDocExists(recipeID.toString()) ==
          true) {
        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> recipesSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes').get();
        for(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc in recipesSnapshot.docs){
          final data = doc.data();
          recipes.add(
            Recipes(
              recipeID: doc.id,
              recipeName: data['recipe_name'],
              recipeDescription: data['recipe_description'],
              recipeURL: data['recipeImageURL'],
              recipeRating: data['recipe_rating'],
              recipeTime: data['recipe_time'],
              recipeIngredients: (data['recipe_ingredients'] as List<dynamic>?)?.cast<String>(),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
    return recipes;
    //} catch (e) {
    //return [];
    //}
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the abpve answer it works for me.
Can you please tell why It shows me `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'` at this line `recipeIngredients: doc.get('recipe_ingredients')` also when I pass the hard coded data it also show me this error `Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform` Please help me to solve me this problem. I will be very thankful.

Comment: Sorry need to cast List `recipeIngredients: (doc['recipe_ingredients'] as List<dynamic>).cast<String>()`, And edited my answer

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but still got this error:
```E/flutter ( 5772): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
E/flutter ( 5772): #0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:87:7)```

Comment: Try change to `[]` instead of `get`

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: I updated answer. This may cause due to data not present, Can you try with my edited answer again.

Comment: I tried your updated answers but the error still continues. There is data present in my firestore database as you can see it in database reference image in my question

Comment: Please add your updated code in your answer

Comment: I added the updated code at the bottom of my question

Comment: Look at my last update answer, I introduced local variable `final data = doc.data();` and user to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and sorry if i disturb you. I got my work done after 3 days hard work